# Why I am getting prediction score 1 i.e. 100%

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, regression, pandas

I am reading few parameters and trying to predict target value using Linear regression and GB. Surpicingly I am getting score = 1 on test data. How come? Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

````
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = pd.read_csv("prod_data_for_ML.csv",header = 0)

#Data Pre-processing
data = dataset.drop('organization_id',1)
data = data.drop('status',1)
data = data.drop('city',1)

#Find median for features having NaN
median_zip, median_role_id, median_specialty_id, median_latitude, median_longitude = data['zip'].median(),data['role_id'].median(),data['specialty_id'].median(),data['latitude'].median(),data['longitude'].median() 
data['zip'].fillna(median_zip, inplace=True)
data['role_id'].fillna(median_role_id, inplace=True)
data['specialty_id'].fillna(median_specialty_id, inplace=True)
data['latitude'].fillna(median_latitude, inplace=True)
data['longitude'].fillna(median_longitude, inplace=True)

#Fill YearOFExp with 0
data['years_of_experience'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

#Start training

labels = dataset.location_id
train1 = data
reg = LinearRegression()
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(train1 , labels , test_size = 0.20,random_state =1)

# x_train.to_csv("x_train.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
# x_test.to_csv("x_test.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
reg.score(x_test,y_test)
```
````

Comment: You try to predict the column `location_id` and you keep that column in your training data. Try this `train1 = data.drop("location_id")`

Comment: Please also read this fantastic article concerning training, testing and validation data sets: https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/

Answer (score 1):

You are using your target variable `location_id` as a feature. You need to remove it from `data`/`train1`/ X variables.

In other words, you are trying to predict `location_id` by `location_id`.

If you use `reg.feature_importances_` you will see, that `location_id` affects your prediction 100% and others have no effect on prediction result.